# Alter in a sentence

Tags: verbs, phrases

I want to say about changing a tradition, formerly elders used to gift goods to children, whereas nowadays their gifting money, can I say "gifting money is altered gifting goods"?

Answer (score 1):

No. *Alter* doesn't fit, either semantically or syntactically.

First, *alter* is nearly always transitive "X alters Y [by doing Z]". You can probably find examples of "X alters" (meaning "X is changed"), but you are far more likely to see a passive for this sense ("X is altered").

Secondly, *alter* almost always implies that somebody is intentionally changing something - even if it is passive and the agent is unexpressed, it is normally understood to imply that the change was intentional.

Thirdly, we do not usually talk about something *altering/being altered **into** something else*: the implication of *alter* is that a change is made, but not to make it into something else.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence is clear and correct (except for the misspelling of "they're")

The second phrase is unclear. The function of "altered" is difficult to parse (I think you want it to function as an adjective, but on first reading it seems to be a verb participle. The use of "altered" (as a participle or an adjective) is not correct, that's not what "altered" really means.

So, in short, no. Your phrase is hard to understand.

Comment: "The custom of giving goods to one's children has changed to one of giving money."